# Eye-tracking for code editing

Tags: mouse, usability, typing, human-computer-interface, eye-tracking

Is there a decent **eye tracking** package to **replace the mouse** for **code editing**?

I want to free up the mouse, but **keep** using **my keyboard** for editing code.

Having done some research on it, I concluded that proper eye tracking hardware is expensive. Using a webcam or high resolution video camera seems to be the most viable option.

Unfortunately, image-based tracking (as opposed to infra-red tracking) restricts the accuracy, and so not all features might be practical.

### Desired eye-tracking IDE features:

- Page scrolling
- Tab selection
- Setting cursor position
- Selecting gaze-focused text with keyboard

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683461/webcam-based-eye-tracking-heatmaps) recommends [Opengazer](http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/opengazer/) for webcams, but I am particularly interested in speeding up basic text-editing. Any recommendations are appreciated, especially if you have experience with eye tracking and practical use cases.

Answer (score 4):

The kind of accuracy you're looking for is pretty difficult to achieve (Since text tends to be pretty small).

IR tracking is actually pretty easy to accomplish. A few IR LEDs and an IR camera (which is really just a normal camera with different filters) and your pupil lights up (This can be done with under $100, more if you want a better camera though).

It's the head tracking that might be more of an issue.

You end up with quite a few degrees of freedoms that you need to track and your inaccuracies will just build up.

Comment: Thanks. Would wearing a head-mounted camera negate most noise issues?

Comment: The head mounted camera would increase accuracy of the eye tracking. The issue is, to track where on a screen one is looking, you have to track the head as well.

Comment: Can’t we use gyros for that? Or, build a set of infrared LEDs into the headset as well, and then use a second, stationary camera to track *those* (thus giving us *independant* data-points for head-location/orientation and eye-orientation) …

Comment: You can, but now you're introducing more variables to track and more noise.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure there is no out-of-the-box solution for problem, but on [eyewriter.org](http://www.eyewriter.org/) there are really nice instructions how to build your own eye-tracker. It's accurate enought to let someone "draw" graphities using only his eyes. so it should be possible to convert the eye-movements into mouse-events.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done reasonably accurately (al la [this article](http://omergertel.com/2010/07/04/how-to-read-code/) on how people read code) but i've never seen a commercial product that does what you're asking for

Maybe take a look at [Emotiv's headsets](http://emotiv.com/), they use thought patterns to perform tasks. They're designed for games but you can probably repurpose it for normal tasks

Answer (score 2):

Re text cursor placement, [Lightning](http://code.google.com/p/text20/) (While I have not worked on this particular feature, I have previously contributed to the Text 2.0 project as a student) which is described in this paper:

[Universal eye-tracking based text cursor warping](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=2168556.2168637)

will place the text cursor at the most salient target in the neighborhood of the gaze position reported by the eye tracker.

However, you need  a Tobii eye tracker that supports the [TET API](http://www.tobii.com/en/eye-tracking-research/global/products/software/tobii-analytics-software-development-kit/tobii-sdk-2-X/). You might want to contact Tobii to verify that the [Tobii X2-30](http://www.tobii.com/en/eye-tracking-research/global/products/hardware/tobii-x2-30-eye-tracker/) eye tracker which costs < $10k is compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Just use vim.  Do more with the keyboard, less with the mouse.

Comment: Do everything with the keyboard.

Comment: I don't understand how this would take away from using the keyboard... If you could just gaze at a place on the screen, and then hit some mapping like, `<leader><leader` very quickly, and have your cursor move to that spot, wouldn't you still only be using the keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I had an issue always having to reach for a normal mouse, looked at various option eyetracking/voice/touchscreen and ended up changing the keyboard to a [IBM Trackpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687/keyboard-for-programmers/430825#430825) end result being my hands never leave the Keyboard and my typing speed and accuracy improved due to not having to reposition my right hand.

Comment: Think I'm going to look into this.

Comment: @FreshCode What did you end up going with?

Answer (score 1):

Eye Tribe has a $99 consumer-level eye tracker that is available now.

> “Using a webcam or high resolution video camera seems to be the most
>   viable option.”

Eye Tribe is a spinoff of Gaze Group, a research group located at the IT University of Copenaghen. The people of Gaze Group developed the open-source ITU GazeTracker software, which allows people to turn low-cost webcams into eye trackers.

http://www.gazegroup.org/downloads

Upon looking at the “downloads” section for Gaze Group, it seems that there are already some eye tracking applications to do some basic actions.

melhosseiny mentioned the [Text 2.0 framework](http://code.google.com/p/text20/) for creating eye tracking apps using HTML, CSS and JavaScript, and the [Universal eye-tracking based text cursor warping](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=2168556.2168637) feature for placing the text cursor at the most salient target.

Eye Tribe has its own SDK, but those things above could help if they work with Eye Tribe.